# How to write dataframe to excel and change format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this, print(df['Date']):

```
0    2018-05-14
1    2018-05-14
2    2018-05-14
3    2018-05-15
```

But when I wrote it to excel, I had no idea why it showed:

```
2018-05-14 00:00:00
2018-05-14 00:00:00
2018-05-14 00:00:00
2018-05-15 00:00:00
```

I don't need time and I want 'yyyy/mm/dd' format, I added format, but it didn't work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'yyyy/mm/dd'}) 
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 15,date_format)
```

So, I added datetime_format in ExcelWriter:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter',datetime_format='yyyy/mm/dd')
```

it did work, but why? 
1. Why can't I use add_format to change?
2. If I want a vertical alignment, I used set_align('vcenter'), it still can't work, how to do?

Comment: *it did work, but why?*.Pandas applies a cell format with the date format to the worksheet data. Since the cells already have a format the column format isn't applied. I'm not sure how to workaround it apart form undefining the default date format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an Excel issue. The reason you are seeing this behaviour is because `pandas` writes `datetime` series as `datetime` objects, which attach a specific representation in Excel.

If you want a specific string format, then you need to convert your `datetime` series to strings before you write to Excel:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

I recommend you ask your second question separately with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this before, but now I found if I put 
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') in front my for loop, it worked; if I put it in my for loop, it showed 
"AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"
I am not sure why the results are different?

Comment: And as resolving date format problem, my second question is also be resolved.

Comment: @SoraLiu, For your first question, this code should be applied *before* your `for` loop. If you use it within your `for` loop, it will not work. Since for your second iteration it will expect a `dt` accessor for a `str` column, which doesn't exist.